# Load Cart Total Block using Ajax

Tags: cart, ajax, discount, totals

I am allowing user to apply some discount amount on cart page. When user clicks on checkbox or enter manually, it will call ajax action and display the discount amount in cart totals block as shown below.

[image: Discount Amount Block]

[image: Cart total after Discount Applied]

How can I load cart totals block using ajax and show discounted amount, when user clicks on checkbox ?

**[EDIT]**

Note: This question has been asked before, but as I still do not have an answer for it or some code flow, it compelled me to ask it again. You can still post some reference close to this question in terms of ajax with magento and container updaation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a custom module;
2. Create a controller
3. On checkbox click call that controller with Ajax
4. Inside the controller place this:

   ```
   $totalsBlock = $layout->createBlock('checkout/cart_totals')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/totals.phtml');
   return $totalsBlock;
   ```
5. On ajax success, replace the content of totals div.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the `$totalsBlock` gives me null.

Comment: Are you sure? I did something similar to this like one week ago and I copied the code from over there. The difference was that I also loaded the checkout/cart block and the totals block was appended to the cart block. Also I had this line too but I think it doesn't do anything: $this->getResponse()->setBody($totalsblock);

Comment: I used `toHtml()` for block rendering, but I cant see the block loaded completely with discount applied unless I reload the page. Could you guide me on that ?

Comment: Try this before loading the block: Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);

Comment: `fetch()` is called and I can see my changes for the display, but `collect()` is not called on ajax click and thus its not showing me discount amount

Comment: I have no idea which fetch() and collect() are you talking about and I can't provide you any more insight because I'd have to create the ajax on my environment too to dig more into it. You're on the good path, good luck debugging further. :)

Comment: How did you achieve it ?

Comment: See http://imgur.com/vAafr0G for my controller. As I said, the difference was that I reloaded the whole cart, not just the totals.